# How to overload -v option in python?

Tags: python, argparse, optional-parameters, suppress-warnings, doctest

I am trying to use -v as an argument in argparse, and it works, but it also outputs a verbose message for tests that don't exist in "**main**", and I'm wondering if there is a way to suppress this function that I am pretty positive is linked to doctest (I am also using doctests but not in **main**).  My output looks normal with this message added on top of it:

```
python 1 items had no tests:
__main__ 0 tests in 1 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

To clarify, I have used argparse to create a -v argument successfully (with action=store_true).

An interesting addendum is that the doctest documentation states the following:

You can force verbose mode by passing verbose=True to testmod(), or prohibit it by passing verbose=False. In either of those cases, sys.argv is not examined by testmod() (so passing -v or not has no effect).

However, when I pass -v, even with doctest.testmod(verbose=False), I get this same occurrence.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information.  An `argparse` without a defined `-v` argument should display ` error: unrecognized arguments: -v`.

Comment: Defining and using an `argparse` parser, does not prevent other parts of the code, such as `doctest` from looking at the commandline values.  `sys.argv` can be read independently by several parsers.

Comment: @hpaulj how to fix this?

Comment: Use some other argument flag in your own parser?  If my guess is right that a `doctest` parser is also looking at `sys.argv`, you should avoid overlapping flags.  It looks like the `doctest` `main` (`doctest._test`) defines arguments for `-v`,`-o`,and `-f`.

Comment: that's what I did.  I was just hoping there was a way to overload it.